# a question on a dependent clause of manner with direct quotes

Tags: punctuation

The following is the last sentence of the text in a reputable textbook.

**As Daniel Goldin of NASA observed,'Finding life elsewhere would change everything. No human endeavor or thought would be unchanged by it.'**

Please note the comma after 'observed' and the direct quote marks(i.e., **'  '**) around the two sentences after the verb 'observed.' It appears to me that the quoted ones are the object clauses for the outer manner clause introduced by '**As**.' Has the entire sentence missed an independent clause?

Comment: What comes before the comma is a dependent clause. This is followed by the quotation, which is comprised of two independent clauses. You can remove the quotation marks and put *finding* in lowercase if you want to see it work without a quotation, or you can replace *observed* with *said* if you want it to use traditional dialogue tags. There is nothing missing.

Comment: @Jason Bassford, thanks for the prompt comment. Got you! I intrepreted the quoted sentences as a part of the the dependent clause (i.e., the 'object' clause of 'observed' as a transitive verb), you intrepret 'observed' as an intransitve verb in this case, thus, 'As Daniel Goldin of NASA observed,' is a complete dependent clause.

Comment: I disagree with @JasonBassford. The reported speech functions as complement of the reporting verb "observed". However, this complement is not a subordinate clause of any kind. What is embedded happens to have the form of a clause, but in fact the construction involves the embedding of text, not a clause as such. Thus the only independent clause is the sentence as a whole